# Simulating p-values for Chi-Squared Test using Monte-Carlo Method

Tags: r, testing, statistics, simulation

I'm trying to write a script in R that allows to aproximate by simulation the critical values (p-values) for a Pearson Chi Squared test, taking different alpha values.

I know that an option in "chisq.test" exists, but I want to know how to do this simulation by hand.

For example:

Please check the code at http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/teaching/stat371/comp21.R (I don't know how to put the code properly)

If you check the last part ("p-value by simulation"), you'll see the way p-value are obtained in the script. I want to do this, but taking different alpha values.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is too broad and you will get the best answer by reading some books. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: so what is your question ... ? What have you tried? ... have you dug into the code for `chisq.test` ... ?

Comment: Yes, I'll be more specific.

I tried this: 

http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/teaching/stat371/comp21.R

But I don't know how to take different alpha values for the simulations of p-value.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you modify your question to reflect this?

Comment: But that script doesn't appear to specify *any* alpha values: instead, it computes the exact p-value as follows: `mean(xsqsim >= xsq)`.  Based on this p-value, you can choose any alpha level you want for rejection / failure to reject the null hypothesis ...

Comment: Sorry. I want to calculate this critical values like p-value is calculated in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have done a simulation as shown in the script, and have derived a vector of simulation values `xsqsim`, then the critical value for an alpha level of `alpha` is *approximately*

```
quantile(xsqsim,1-alpha)
```

You have to be a little bit careful if you have a small sample, because the critical value should be the value of the test statistic *q* such that the probability of the observed value being greater than **or equal to** *q* is equal to alpha ...

Answer (score 2):

The **calculation** of p-value of any statistical test (whatever method: classical, bootstrap) has nothing to do with alpha value if you mean significance level by that. You need alpha value when making a decision to accept or reject the null hypothesis (if p-value is less than **chosen** alpha then reject the null).